# Multiple Selection using g:select

Tags: grails, parameters, selection

I am currently trying to implement 3 drop down menus that are based off of the previous selection. Out of the 3 selections I have the last two working with each other. I have the value that the first drop down is supposed to supply being static to test the other two selections which works perfectly. But now when I'm trying to add the the correct selections to the first drop down the selection itself disappears when I go to select the second drop down AND it also does not pass the value that was selected in the first drop down. Here is the code for my three drop down menus that are effect from each selection in the previous drop down:

```
%{--Selection of specific site location--}%

<g:select name="locationSelection" from="${location_names}" 
    value="${params.site_id}" optionKey="location_id" 
    optionValue="short_name" noSelection="['': '----Site----']"
    onchange="${remoteFunction(controller: 'term', action: 'findWeeksForSemester',
    params: '\'location_id=\' + this.value', update: 'locationSelection',
    options: '[asynchronous: false]')}"/>  

<br>

%{--Selection of specific semester--}%

<g:select name="termSelection" id="termSelection" from="${result}"
    value="${params.term_id}" style="" optionKey="semester_id"
    optionValue="semester_name" noSelection="['': '----Term----']"
    onchange="${remoteFunction(controller: 'term', action: 'findWeeksForSemester',
    params: '\'semester_id=\' + this.value', update: 'weekSelection',
    options: '[asynchronous: false]', onComplete: 'updateWeekSelection()')}"/>

<br>

%{--Selection of specific week--}%

<g:select name="weekSelection" from="" noSelection="['': '----Week----']" 
    onchange="${remoteFunction(controller: 'term', action: 'testRemote',
    onSuccess: 'testRemote(data)', params: '\'semester_id=\' + this.value')}"/>
```

I'm currently trying to assign the selected value to `location_id`, which is a parameter, and have it print out in my controller to confirm the value it should be but the value that is always passed is null and the selection from the first drop down menu goes away upon trying to select something from the second drop down menu. Is there some crucial I'm missing as to why this isn't working?

Comment: I think you have a problem with 'from' param on g:select, there you include the list of items to iterate. Can you specify the data structure of ${location_names} and ${result}? Are you sure about 'location_names' has the attribute 'location_id' that you are including with 'option_key'?

Comment: It's an array from a query that is ran before the page loads. 


This is is `location_names`: `[[location_id:2, short_name:Center], [location_id:6, short_name:Charlie], [location_id:17, short_name:Alpha], [location_id:19, short_name:Bravo]]`